# Unable to stream avro formated data coming from Kafka Debezium connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

Im streaming mongo oplog data though Kafka. Im using Debezium CDC Kafka connector to tail mongo oplog.

Schema registry uses AvroConverter convertor for serialising keys and value

> bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
>
> Kafka key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter 
>   key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 
>   value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter 
>   value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
>
> internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
>   internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
>   internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false 
>   internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
>
> offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

Below code stream the Kafka data and deserialise it using **KafkaAvroDeserializer**

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
object KafkaStream{

  case class DeserializedFromKafkaRecord(key: String, value: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("kafka")
      .getOrCreate()
    //sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import sparkSession.implicits._



    val schemaRegistryURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8081"

    val topicName = "prodCollection.inventory.Prod"
    val subjectValueName = topicName + "-value"

    //create RestService object
    val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)

    //.getLatestVersion returns io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.Schema object.
    val valueRestResponseSchema = restService.getLatestVersion(subjectValueName)

    //Use Avro parsing classes to get Avro Schema
    val parser = new Schema.Parser
    val topicValueAvroSchema: Schema = parser.parse(valueRestResponseSchema.getSchema)

    //key schema is typically just string but you can do the same process for the key as the value
    val keySchemaString = "\"string\""
    val keySchema = parser.parse(keySchemaString)

    //Create a map with the Schema registry url.
    //This is the only Required configuration for Confluent's KafkaAvroDeserializer.
    val props = Map("schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryURL)

    //Declare SerDe vars before using Spark structured streaming map. Avoids non serializable class exception.
    var keyDeserializer: KafkaAvroDeserializer = null
    var valueDeserializer: KafkaAvroDeserializer = null

    //Create structured streaming DF to read from the topic.
    val rawTopicMessageDF = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", topicName)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("key.deserializer","KafkaAvroDeserializer")
      .option("value.deserializer","KafkaAvroDeserializer")
      //.option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 20)  //remove for prod
      .load()
    rawTopicMessageDF.printSchema()

    //instantiate the SerDe classes if not already, then deserialize!
    val deserializedTopicMessageDS = rawTopicMessageDF.map{
      row =>
        if (keyDeserializer == null) {
          keyDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer
          keyDeserializer.configure(props.asJava, true)  //isKey = true
        }
        if (valueDeserializer == null) {
          valueDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer
          valueDeserializer.configure(props.asJava, false) //isKey = false
        }

        //Pass the Avro schema.
        val deserializedKeyString = keyDeserializer.deserialize(topicName, row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("key"), keySchema).toString //topic name is actually unused in the source code, just required by the signature. Weird right?
      val deserializedValueJsonString = valueDeserializer.deserialize(topicName, row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value"), topicValueAvroSchema).toString

        DeserializedFromKafkaRecord(deserializedKeyString, deserializedValueJsonString)
    }
    deserializedTopicMessageDS.printSchema()

      deserializedTopicMessageDS.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", false)
      .start()
```

deserializedTopicMessageDS dataset schema is getting converted as required however stream is getting stoped with below information,

```
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO StreamExecution: Starting [id = b1fb3ce2-08d0-4d87-b031-af129432d91a, runId = 38b66e4a-040f-42c8-abbe-bc27fa3b9462]. Use /private/var/folders/zf/6dh44_fx1sn2dp2w7d_54wg80000gn/T/temporary-ae7a93f6-0307-4f39-ba44-93d5d3d7c0ab to store the query checkpoint.
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.0.100:4040
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = spark-kafka-source-b9f0f64b-952d-4733-ba3e-aa753954b2ef--1115279952-driver-0
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/zf/6dh44_fx1sn2dp2w7d_54wg80000gn/T/spark-e1c2b259-39f2-4d65-9919-74ab1ad6acae
18/08/13 22:53:54 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/zf/6dh44_fx1sn2dp2w7d_54wg80000gn/T/temporary-ae7a93f6-0307-4f39-ba44-93d5d3d7c0ab

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Does it mean anything in log? *Use /private/var/folders/zf/6dh44_fx1sn2dp2w7d_54wg80000gn/T/temporary-ae7a93f6-0307-4f39-ba44-93d5d3d7c0ab to store the query checkpoint.*

Comment: Not sure as it getting deleted at the end.

Comment: One thing im unable to understand here is if data is being by serialised using Avro format then it should be deserialized using same class. however, in the result ByteArrayDeserializer is taken as value deserializer. Can anyone please explain whats happening here.

Comment: In Kafka AvroMessage means, stream of bytes..

Comment: In that case, am i doing any mistake in deserializing data?